# running Scala threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, http

I am an absolute beginner in Scala, but have this problem to solve.
So i have a list of parameters

```
itemList = List('abc', 'def', 'ghi','jkl','mno', 'pqr')
```

I have these 3 parameter queries

```
 val q1 = "env='dev1'&id='123'&listitem='xyz'"
 val q2 = "env='dev2'&id='1234'&listitem='xyz'"
 val q3 = "env='dev3'&id='12345'&listitem='xyz'"

 val report1 = getReport(q1)
 val report2 = getReport(q2)
 val report3 = getReport(q3)
```

So I am trying to loop through the list, replace the listitem parameter in q1, q2 and q3 with the listitem and then run the http request report for each item in the list.

Since each getReport request is asynchronous, i need to wait , and so i cannot go to the next item in the list, as it would be if i were to do a loop.

So i would like to start up 3 threads for each item in the list and then combine the 3 reports into 1 final one, or i could do it sequentially.

How would i go about doing it with 3 Threads for each item in the list?
This is my idea:

```
val reportToken = [ q1, q2,q3 ]
val listTasks = [ getReport(q1) , getReport(q2) , getReport(q3) ]

for (i <- 1 to 3) {
    val thread = new Thread {
        override def run {
            listTasks (reportToken(i))
        }
   val concat += listTask(i) 
    }
    thread.start
    Thread.sleep(50)  
}
```

Comment: much easier with `Future` than with `Thread`

Comment: ok I agree, how would you go about it with Future? :-)

Comment: try it and let us know where you get stuck?

Comment: ok yea sounds good

Comment: `Future.sequence(listTasks.map(Future.apply))`

Comment: @Dima thanks! could you give some more details? hard time connecting the dots with what you wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap each of your tasks in a `Future`, apply `map/recover` to handle the successful/failed Futures, and use `Future.sequence` to transform the list of Futures into a `Future of list`.  Here's a trivialized example:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

def getReport(q: String) = q match {
  case "q2" => throw new Exception()
  case q => s"got $q"
}

val reportToken = Seq("q1", "q2", "q3")
val listTasks = reportToken.map( q => Future{ getReport(q) } )
// listTasks: Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[String]] = ...

val f = Future.sequence(
  listTasks.map(_.map(Some(_)).recover{case _ => None})
)
// f: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[Option[String]]] = ...

Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
// res1: Seq[Option[String]] = List(Some(got q1), None, Some(got q3))
```

For more details about Futures, here's a relevant [Scala doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Comment: thanks!, it returns nothing though, the program just stops

Comment: @uniXVanXcel, I ran it on Scala shell for proof of concept.  To unwrap the result list from Future and Option, you can apply `onSuccess`, like: `Future.sequence(...).onSuccess{ case list => println(list.flatten) }`

Comment: oh i see maybe that’s why - i created an object and i think i need to add a sleep function at the end so that it keeps running ?

Comment: I would suggest using `Await.result()`.  Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: got it to work!, was passing the wrong string in my argument to Future{}  - thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `def getReport(str: String): Future[HttpResponse]`

```
Future.sequence(itemList.map( item => {
for {
  report1 <- getReport(q1.replace("xyz", item))
  report2 <- getReport(q2.replace("xyz", item))
  report3 <- getReport(q3.replace("xyz", item))
} yield {
  (report1, report2, report3)
}
})).onComplete {
   case Success(res) => // do something
   case Failure(err) => // handle error
}
```